# I am updating code mysql to mysqli now i am get stuck in is_resource method

Tags: php

I am spending almost a day to figure out an error related to is_resource method here is my code

```
function __construct() {
    $this->dbHost = "localhost";
    $this->dbUser = "root";
    $this->dbPass = "";
    $this->dbName = "tahseent_digitemb";
}
public function connect() {
    $this->dbh = mysqli_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass)
   ;6     or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysqli_error($this->dbh));
    mysqli_select_db($this->dbh, $this->dbName) 
        or die("Database error:<br />" . mysqli_error($this->dbh));
        if(!is_resource($this->dbh)) {
        trigger_error("Unable to Connect to the Database Server: ".$this->dbHost, E_USER_ERROR);
        //die("Error:: Unable to Connect to the Database Server.");
    }
    if(!mysqli_select_db($this->dbh, $this->dbname)) {
        trigger_error("Unable to Select Database:: ".$this->dbname, E_USER_ERROR);
        //die("Error:: Unable to Select Database"); 
    }
```

I am connecting to my database successfully because my connection have not die but i can
t understand why is_resource method showing false result. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLI doesn't use resources, it uses objects. `mysqli_connect` returns an object of class `mysqli`, `mysql_prepare` returns an object of class `mysqli_stmt`, and `mysqli_query` returns an object of class `mysqli_result` when performing a `SELECT` query.

All these functions return `false` if they fail. Instead of testing whether the returned value is a resource, just test whether it's truthy:

```
$this->dbh = mysqli_connect(...);
if ($this->dbh) {
    // successfull
} else {
    // report error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_connect`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is an alias for the [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class constructor, so `$this->dbh` is not a resource but rather an object. The appropriate test would be with `is_object` or perhaps `instanceof mysqli`.

That said, there is no need to test. Your initial `or die` test will already have caught any errors.